# Import adjustment layer from Photoshop to After Effects

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects, adobe-after-effects

can I import - and use - adjustment layers from Photoshop to After Effects? I don't want to generate all my gradiation curves once again. Is there a chance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow these steps:

Organize your Photoshop file. Name your layers meaningfully so you won't have to figure out what they contain. Avoid duplicate names, particularly for layers of different types.

Unlock any locked layers, including your "Background" layer if your file contains one. Otherwise, some layers won't work correctly in After Effects.

Convert your file to RGB or Grayscale if it isn't already in one of these two color modes. After Effects imports layered files in other color modes as flattened, single-layer files.

Add placeholder layers to your file if you anticipate adding more content to it. After Effects can recognize new content on these layers later if they exist in your Photoshop document before you import it.

Crop your Photoshop file to eliminate areas you don't plan to use in After Effects. This reduces the amount of memory After Effects needs to manipulate to render your file.

Save your file in Photoshop Document (PSD) format. Make sure the file name ends with the ".psd" file extension.

Open your After Effects document. Go to the "File" Menu and choose "File" from the "Import" option.

Navigate to where you saved your PSD file. Choose "Composition - Retain Layer Sizes" as the import mode to retain the positions of Photoshop layers relative to one another, and bring your imagery into After Effects the way it looks in Photoshop.

Read more at given links : http://www.ehow.com/how_7206280_bring-photoshop-layers-ae.html

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AfterEffects/9.0/WS3878526689cb91655866c1103906c6dea-7f53a.html